# Issues with callback function

Tags: javascript, api

I have a very simple question but it has been bouncing all over my head how to handle this. I've been using this API that requires a callback function to capture the values, and i'm having issues in returning the output of the function to other functions that i'm using on my project.

For example:

```
function a() {
var callback = function(e) {
  var id = e.data.responseData.Id;
};
Api.getId(callback);    
}
```

If i try to call the variable id, it will give me undefined so i'm assuming that the id value is not being passed available globally.

On the other side if i run something like this:

```
function a() {
    var callback = function(e) {
      var id = e.data.responseData.Id;
      console.log(id);
    };
    Api.getId(callback);    
    }
```

It will return me on the console correctly the value of id.

Any ideas on what i'm missing here?

Thanks once again.

Rafa

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. There is no return statement in the entire code example you have given. Which function should return something?

Comment: Is suppose to return the id value. I've tried adding the "return id" but also didn't work. Essentially i want to use id on other functions outside of that scope.

Comment: You can't return a value asynchronously. If you have to use `id` in other functions, call those functions from the callback function passing `id` as an argument. Example - `var callback = function(){ id = getId(); foo(id);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to return variable "id" in function:

```
function a() {
var callback = function(e) {
  var id = e.data.responseData.Id;
  return id;
};
Api.getId(callback);    
}
```

Comment: I've tried and still was giving me null.

Comment: It will return the `id` inside `Api` function where the callback is called. Thus, the value `id` is not usable in function a().

Comment: yes, you're right, and then  should be Api.getId(callback); returned as well :)